# How to find an attributes holding class or id?

Tags: jquery, object, jquery-selectors, attributes

I am trying to run an action on a specified class by determining the value of its data attribute. The problem I'm running into is I cant find the attributes class/selector, not sure how to get to an attributes selector.

jQuery .find, .closest etc doesn't work because I can see I'm no longer in that class, but rather pulling [object Object], which unfortunately I'm unfamiliar with.

Any help on this would be great!

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
(function () {
    var currentDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('DD,d MM yy', new Date());
    if ($(".post-title").data('date') < currentDate) {
        //  console.log($(this));
        $(this).css({
            "opacity": "0.5",
                "border": "2px solid red"
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: maybe some life example?

Comment: Note: .data('date') will be a string, not a date. Comparing this to a date object will not work.

Comment: for `this` to reference specific `.post-title` element, you need to use an `each` loop if there is more than one element of this class

Comment: @Diodeus If `.data('date')` was saved as a `Date` object, it should be retrieved as one.

Comment: Here is a fiddle. I need to effect only the expired post and leave teh active one alone

http://jsfiddle.net/MVFW9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `each`, it provides a closure for you to work within. Then `this` will refer to the current jQuery object/element (even if there is only one matching element).

```
$('.post-title').each(function () {
  if (new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() < new Date().getTime()) {
    $(this).css({
      opacity: 0.5,
      border: '2px solid red'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly, very clean and to the point. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `this` does not refer to the `post-title` element. Also your date comparison need to be changed, it has to compare date not string

You need to use a each loop if there can be multiple elements

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var date = new Date();
    var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());

    $(".post-title").each(function () {
        var date = $.datepicker.parseDate('DD,d MM yy', $(this).data('date'));
        if (date < today) {
            //  console.log($(this));

            $(this).css({
                "opacity": "0.5",
                    "border": "2px solid red"
            });
        }
    })

})
```

if not

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var date = new Date();
    var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());

    var date = $.datepicker.parseDate('DD,d MM yy', $title.data('date'));
    if (date < today) {
        $title.css({
            "opacity": "0.5",
                "border": "2px solid red"
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: @user3111851 the `new Date(string)` may not always works fine based on the local used by the client